# How to get Outlook.NameSpace.CurrentUser value?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

```
Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application = GetApplicationObject()
Dim ns As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace = Nothing
Dim inboxFolder As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

ns.CurrentUser = Username
```

I'm trying to get `.CurrentUser` value to Username data item.

I get this compiler error:

> Property 'CurrentUser' is 'ReadOnly'

How can I get it`s value? Tried to use Get Return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Username = ns.CurrentUser.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to set the current user in Outlook which is not possible. The property, like the error message states, is read only. If you want to get the user name you need to have the operand on the right-hand side of the assignment operator:

The [CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property of the Namespace class returns the currently logged-on user as a [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object which represents a user or resource in Outlook, generally a mail or mobile message addressee. The [Recipient.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.name) property returns a string value that represents the display name for the object.

```
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
Dim recipient as Outlook.Recipient
Dim userName as string

myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
recipient = myNameSpace.CurrentUser 
userName = recipient.Name
```